# JQuery DataTables - Quantidade dos Números da Paginação

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-datatables, datatable

Estou implementando a paginação do DataTables e não consegui descobrir como modificar a quantidade de botões de Número da paginação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, temos de **1** a **5**, ou poderíamos ter de **7** a **11** os números da Página, ou seja, sempre **5 números**. Eu gostaria de mostrar **10 números**, por exemplo: **1** a **10** ou **3** a **13** ou **7** a **17** ou **11** a **21**, etc.

Espero que eu tenha sido claro! Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode alterar o número de páginas que aparecem, alterando a variavel jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.iFullNumbersShowPages, que por padrão é 5. Ex.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.iFullNumbersShowPages = 10;
$('#my-table').extend.dataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "bScrollCollapse": true
});
```

Segue link com explicação (em inglês): http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/dataTables-1.4/example_alt_pagination.html

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma mais simples seria configurar a propriedade "iDisplayLength" do componente dataTable. Assim:

```
$('#dtPagina').dataTable({                         
  "iDisplayLength": 100                         
});
```